# How do I create CGI scripts with Perl?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am creating a website and done with some HTML stuff, but I am thinking to create site using CGI and Perl scripting. I don't have much idea on CGI scripting. Can anyone please suggest me how to create a CGI script and how to create web pages with that?

Comment: Catchy name there! ... At times like this I'm reminded of Pierre De Fermat's marginal note which said something like "I have discovered a truly marvellous proof of this proposition which this margin is too small to contain" and the world had to figure it out by themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [A Beginner's Introduction to Perl Web Programming](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2008/09/a-beginners-introduction-to-pe.html) on [perl.com](http://www.perl.com).

I would recommend you make use of tools like [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) or [Markapl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Markapl/) to make the process of producing and maintaining your HTML view much simpler.

And moving forward you might want to consider looking at using a [web framework](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?web_frameworks) ranging from something very light like [Squatting](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Squatting/) to a powerful beast like [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Try [Ovid's CGI Course](http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/) - it's a good start. "A Beginner's Introduction to Perl Web Programming" is also a good reading, but with less information.

Later you can try framework like CGI::Application - it should be easy even for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

CGI is a standard to interface a webserver and a content provider or external application (let's say a Perl script, a compiled program), I think you better study Perl to code some CGI.

This link is a [beginner guide](http://www.lies.com/begperl/) to get started with CGI coding in Perl.

Also if you are beginner in Perl you might look to some other scripting language more dedicated to web, the best example is PHP. But if you are already experienced Perl CGI, the CGI.pm is nice also.

Comment: Tutorial is slightly outdated - no "use strict", no lexical filehandles, ...
As for PHP - it should not be used by beginner because of serious style problems like mixing HTMl and code.

Comment: Why learn  a dedicated language? Perl (Ruby and Python, too) provides great tools for making websites, and they are also useful for general purpose programming tasks.  Back when I was deciding what language to learn for web tasks, I chose Perl specifically because of its general usefulness for other tasks. This decision has paid off handsomely for me. IMO, the convenience of PHP does not outweigh its limited applicability. Also, that tutorial is more than a little dated, it talks about using a version of perl that dates from June 1997.

Comment: you can do clean code in php, yeah most people are mixing too much HTML and PHP but the language don't force you. I mean PHP is more intuitive to a beginner and you can achieve stuff more easily then in perl. 

But it doesn't mean that perl or php is better just it depend what you want to do. In his case he seems to be a beginner so I don't know if perl is the easiest language to learn for a beginner. Just my thoughts

Comment: also last point you can do normal scripting with php as well ... it is not dedicated to web it just happen most of people use it only for web.